# R - HTML parser to check whether some HTML is mostly bold, italic etc

Tags: html, r

I have a column of HTML. For each row of my column, I'd like to determine (yes/no) whether the contents is bold, italics, etc. Many of the HTML snippets have some parts bold, and some parts not, for example. So I would want to flag it as bold if it is more than, say, 50% bold.

For example, this one should be flagged as bold and italic:

`html <- "<p id="PARA339" style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN: 0pt; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.25"><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman, Times, serif"><i><b>We had a net loss of $1.</b></i><i><b>55</b></i><i><b> million for the year ended December 31, 201</b></i><i><b>6</b></i><i><b> and have an accumulated deficit of $</b></i><i><b>61.5</b></i><i><b> million as of December 31, 201</b></i><i><b>6</b></i><i><b>. To achieve sustainable profitability, we must generate increased revenue.</b></i></font></p>"`

How do I approach this? I was considering using regex to count characters between  **and** , but a proper HTML parser would be better. I don't know what package to use or where to start. Thanks

Comment: How would your expected output look like?

Comment: I would just like a True or false for whether it is bold, italic etc. I plan to make each of these possible styles a column of True or False

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a HTML parser answer but a regex one :

```
isBold <- function(text) grepl('<b>.*</b>', text)
isItalics <- function(text) grepl('<i>.*</i>', text)

isBold(html)
#[1] TRUE
isItalics(html)
#[1] TRUE
```

**data**

```
html <- '<p id="PARA339" style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN: 0pt; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.25"><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman, Times, serif"><i><b>We had a net loss of $1.</b></i><i><b>55</b></i><i><b> million for the year ended December 31, 201</b></i><i><b>6</b></i><i><b> and have an accumulated deficit of $</b></i><i><b>61.5</b></i><i><b> million as of December 31, 201</b></i><i><b>6</b></i><i><b>. To achieve sustainable profitability, we must generate increased revenue.</b></i></font></p>'
```

---

Instead of only depending on one occurrence of bold or italics tag we can count the proportions of one tag vs the rest and return `TRUE` only if the number is greater than some value.

```
library(stringr)

isItalics <- function(text) str_count(html,'<i>')/str_count(html, '<[bi]>') > 0.5
isBold <- function(text) str_count(html, '<b>')/str_count(html, '<[bi]>') > 0.5

isBold(html)
#[1] FALSE
isItalics(html)
#[1] TRUE
```

This counts the number of occurrences of `b` (or `i`) tags and divide it by  combined occurrence of `b` and `i` tag and return `TRUE` only if it is nigher than 50%. Along with `'<[bi]>'` you can also include more tags if needed.

**Updated data**

```
html <- '<p id="PARA339" style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN: 0pt; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.25"><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman, Times, serif"><i>We had a net loss of $1.</i><i><b>55</b></i><i> million for the year ended December 31, 201</i><i>6</i><i> and have an accumulated deficit of $</i><i>61.5</i><i> million as of December 31, 201</i><i>6</i><i>. To achieve sustainable profitability, we must generate increased revenue.</i></font></p>'
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I run into the issue of many of these paragraphs containing a few words, say, in bold, which is why I need to compute some kind of proportion, and not just flag the whole thing as bold if it contains one bold word.

Comment: Hmmm....Can you provide an example of such text along with expected output?

Comment: Thanks. So, for example, `html <- "<p id="PARA339" style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN: 0pt; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.25"><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman, Times, serif"><i>We had a net loss of $1.</i><i><b>55</b></i><i> million for the year ended December 31, 201</i><i>6</i><i> and have an accumulated deficit of $</i><i>61.5</i><i> million as of December 31, 201</i><i>6</i><i>. To achieve sustainable profitability, we must generate increased revenue.</i></font></p>"` now we only have one word of the text in the bold - so I'd want to just flag that as True: Italic, False: Bold